# PHP Prevent Session Data Sharing between applications

Tags: php, session

How to prevent session from being shared in all of my applications.

I'm using xampp, so if i have a `session['key'] = 'value'` in app A I can't get it in app B.

How to separate session for each application?

Comment: Doesn't seem unclear to me.

Comment: the answers below solved it  , the problem that if i have a session in one application , i will get it in another application unless i change the session name in the second application or chage session path and domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in app A

```
session_name('sessiona'); // SessionA
session_start();
```

in app B

```
session_name('sessionb'); // SessionB
session_start();
```

read [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ini_set("session.save_path", "/your_home/your_sessions/");
```

to set the current session file in your server. Or you can define a domain for the session cookie, like so:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

And then, just start it as

```
session_start();
```